# NLP: compare parsed and tagged sentences

Tags: nlp, nltk

Hello language programmers

I'm studying online natural language processing and so far i have some understanding of how to parse a sentence including getting it's POS tags, SRL and so.
my question is what to do with this data, or more precisely how to compare two different parsed sentences to see how similar they are.

for example i got this tow parsed sentences and i want to be able to compare them

**1.**

```
<sentence id="s0" parse_status="success" fom="11.6633">
<cons id="c0" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c1" sem_head="c1" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c1" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c2" sem_head="c2" schema="head_mod">
<cons id="c2" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c3" sem_head="c3" schema="head_mod">
<cons id="c3" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t0" sem_head="t0">
<tok id="t0" cat="N" pos="NN" base="apartment" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]" pred="noun_arg0">apartment</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c4" cat="PP" xcat="" head="c5" sem_head="c5" schema="head_comp">
<cons id="c5" cat="PX" xcat="" head="t1" sem_head="t1">
<tok id="t1" cat="P" pos="IN" base="in" lexentry="N[<P>NP.acc]" pred="prep_arg12" type="noun_mod" arg1="c3" arg2="c6">in</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c6" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c7" sem_head="c7" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c7" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c9" sem_head="c9" schema="mod_head">
<cons id="c8" cat="NP" xcat="" head="t2" sem_head="t2">
<tok id="t2" cat="N" pos="NNP" base="tel" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]-noun_adjective_rule" pred="noun_arg1" type="noun_mod" arg1="c9">Tel</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c9" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t3" sem_head="t3">
<tok id="t3" cat="N" pos="NNP" base="aviv" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]" pred="noun_arg0">Aviv</tok>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
<cons id="c10" cat="PP" xcat="" head="c11" sem_head="c11" schema="head_comp">
<cons id="c11" cat="PX" xcat="" head="t4" sem_head="t4">
<tok id="t4" cat="P" pos="IN" base="with" lexentry="N[<P>NP.acc]" pred="prep_arg12" type="noun_mod" arg1="c2" arg2="c12">with</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c12" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c13" sem_head="c13" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c13" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c15" sem_head="c15" schema="mod_head">
<cons id="c14" cat="ADJP" xcat="" head="t5" sem_head="t5">
<tok id="t5" cat="ADJ" pos="CD" base="five" lexentry="[<ADJP>]N" pred="adj_arg1" type="noun_mod" arg1="c15">five</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c15" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t6" sem_head="t6">
<tok id="t6" cat="N" pos="NNS" base="room" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]-plural_noun_rule" pred="noun_arg0">rooms</tok>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</sentence>
```

**2.**

```
<sentence id="s1" parse_status="success" fom="17.4367">
<cons id="c16" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c17" sem_head="c17" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c17" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c18" sem_head="c18" schema="head_mod">
<cons id="c18" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t7" sem_head="t7">
<tok id="t7" cat="N" pos="NN" base="apartment" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]" pred="noun_arg0">apartment</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c19" cat="PP" xcat="" head="c20" sem_head="c20" schema="head_comp">
<cons id="c20" cat="PX" xcat="" head="t8" sem_head="t8">
<tok id="t8" cat="P" pos="IN" base="with" lexentry="N[<P>NP.acc]" pred="prep_arg12" type="noun_mod" arg1="c18" arg2="c21">with</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c21" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c22" sem_head="c22" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c22" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c23" sem_head="c23" schema="head_mod">
<cons id="c23" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c25" sem_head="c25" schema="mod_head">
<cons id="c24" cat="ADJP" xcat="" head="t9" sem_head="t9">
<tok id="t9" cat="ADJ" pos="CD" base="-NUMBER-" lexentry="[<ADJP>]N" pred="adj_arg1" type="noun_mod" arg1="c25">3</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c25" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t10" sem_head="t10">
<tok id="t10" cat="N" pos="NNS" base="room" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]-plural_noun_rule" pred="noun_arg0">rooms</tok>
</cons>
</cons>
<cons id="c26" cat="PP" xcat="" head="c27" sem_head="c27" schema="head_comp">
<cons id="c27" cat="PX" xcat="" head="t11" sem_head="t11">
<tok id="t11" cat="P" pos="IN" base="in" lexentry="N[<P>NP.acc]" pred="prep_arg12" type="noun_mod" arg1="c23" arg2="c28">in</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c28" cat="NP" xcat="" head="c29" sem_head="c29" schema="empty_spec_head">
<cons id="c29" cat="NX" xcat="" head="c31" sem_head="c31" schema="mod_head">
<cons id="c30" cat="NP" xcat="" head="t12" sem_head="t12">
<tok id="t12" cat="N" pos="NNP" base="tel" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]-noun_adjective_rule" pred="noun_arg1" type="noun_mod" arg1="c31">Tel</tok>
</cons>
<cons id="c31" cat="NX" xcat="" head="t13" sem_head="t13">
<tok id="t13" cat="N" pos="NNP" base="aviv" lexentry="[D<N.3sg>]" pred="noun_arg0">Aviv</tok>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</cons>
</sentence>
```

thanks

Comment: It's really up to you to decide on a similarity measure. As this question stands, I'm tempted to flag for putting on hold as not demonstrating a basic understanding of the problem definition.

Answer (score 0):

The Zhang and Shasha metrics could be what you are looking for. This metric compute length between two tree in an nlp syntaxe tree. You can look [here(in french)](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_d%27%C3%A9dition_sur_les_arbres), or search for the "Simple fast algorithm for editing distance between tree and related problem" original publication.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to find categorise sentences and club the similar ones.

You can approach this in multiple ways.

1. Use Naive Bayes on tagged sentences to categorise them (assuming you have some training data and limited number of sentence categories).
2. Use linear regression to do the similar process. Include tags and distances between tags as features.
3. Use K-means or similar techniques if you want statistical unsupervised approach.
4. Use linguistic filter model to put the tagged sentences through different filters. (simply like: statement/interrogative or active/passive and many such).

Frankly there are many many ways of solving this problem. It is still not solved completely. But because you mentioned you are studying NLP, I suggest you start with these approaches.